# Aggregation Versus Find/Update in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, nosql, backend

I'm learning to use MongoDB as the backend for an application that requires the user fetch data with some frequency from the server, and have noticed that the aggregation framework seems quite powerful.

So powerful, in fact, that I'm wondering if it obviates the need for me to use `find()` and `updateMany()` at all, among other operators, considering that `.aggregate()` appears to have almost all of the same functionality of those other functions.

What is the point of having these different systems? Is one faster than the other? Why not just have the `.aggregate()` pipeline framework on its own?

And most importantly, when can I know when to use the aggregate pipeline, and when to use the simpler `.find()` and `.update()` functions?

Thanks for your help in understanding all this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Find**

1) The method of fetching or getting data from a MongoDB database is carried out by using queries.

2) While performing a query operation, one can also use criteria’s or conditions which can be used to retrieve specific data from the database.

3) MongoDB provides a function called db.collection.find () which is used for retrieval of documents from a MongoDB database.

**Use**:- For fetching result without too much changes

Mysql example:- `Select * from users where first_name= "John"`

**Aggregation**

1) Aggregation operations process data records and return computed results.

2) Aggregation operations group values from multiple documents together, and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return a single result.

3) Aggregations are a set of functions that allow you to manipulate the data being returned from a MongoDB query.

4) Aggregate function groups the records in a collection, and can be used to provide total number(sum), average, minimum, maximum etc out of the group selected.

I know all point lead you to conclude only one point which is process data records and return computed results.
*Oooh, no it also goes to first point too..*

Use:- Manipulate data as par requirement use Aggregate(sum, count, average, group etc) like mysql,
Mysql example:- `SELECT  user.*, count(*) FROM orders GROUP BY role; (or use joins)`

**Update**

As par your question find and update are not simpler 
 .find() used for fetching and .update() functions used for manipulation/update/change of data for future.

use:- for updates or changes in data (ie. When user wants to change username from "John" to "Jack")
Mysql example:- `UPDATE users SET first_name = 'Jack' WHERE first_name = 'John'`;